# Getting The Last Changes since Last Value Change

Tags: php, object, compare

```
I want to check the last value changes.
Some times the objectId is the same as another objectId but the value can be different.
And i cant compare this to get the Last changes.
How do i do that?
```

This are the  Objects

```
  object(stdClass)#38 (6) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(7) "1715680"
      ["objectId"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["type"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["field"]=>
      string(2) "30"
      ["value"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["date"]=>
      string(10) "1239982220"
    }
    object(stdClass)#39 (6) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(7) "1739382"
      ["objectId"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["type"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["field"]=>
      string(2) "30"
      ["value"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["date"]=>
      string(10) "1240588802"
    }
    object(stdClass)#40 (6) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(7) "1762456"
      ["objectId"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["type"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["field"]=>
      string(2) "30"
      ["value"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["date"]=>
      string(10) "1241195393"
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to get the _value_ field from the newest object (the object with the highest _date_) ?  I think you should try to edit the question and try to be more specific what you want to achieve.

Comment: have a look at the sourcecode this says more than 1000 words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved My Own Question isnt that good?

```
$changed = false;

        while($z = $this->db->fetch($m))
        {
            $array[$z->objectId][$z->field][] = $z;
        }

        for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
        {

            $blogs = $array[1][30];

            foreach($blogs as $blog)
            {
                $blogs[$i];
                if($blog->value != $blogs[$i]->value)
                {
                        $changed = true;
                }


            }

        }
```